# How to open activity from bottom navigation view

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view. I would like to open an activity, not a fragment when clicking on action.item3.
This is the code so far:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_item1:
                                selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item2:
                                selectedFragment = SpotsSearch1Fragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item3:
                                selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item4:
                                selectedFragment = ItemFourFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item5:
                                selectedFragment = ItemFiveFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

I have tried to change the action at case R.id.action_item3: like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
```

But obviously I am getting an exception at line:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
```

Is there a way to open an activity instead a fragment using bottom navigation vie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this way

You can `break` the `switch()` case  at your `R.id.action_item3`  using `return true;`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_item1:
                    selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                    case R.id.action_item2:
                    selectedFragment = SpotsSearch1Fragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                    case R.id.action_item3:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                     return true;
                    case R.id.action_item4:
                    selectedFragment = ItemFourFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                    case R.id.action_item5:
                    selectedFragment = ItemFiveFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                }


                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Fragment` `Transaction` is happening outside of `switch case`. separate `Transaction` logic using function and call where requires.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_item1:
                selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                fragTransaction(selectedFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_item2:
                selectedFragment = SpotsSearch1Fragment.newInstance();
                fragTransaction(selectedFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_item3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.action_item4:
                selectedFragment = ItemFourFragment.newInstance();
                fragTransaction(selectedFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_item5:
                selectedFragment = ItemFiveFragment.newInstance();
                fragTransaction(selectedFragment);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});

private void fragTransaction(Fragment selectedFragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is working fine, but there is another answer prior to yours